# Hilt: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kotlin20test.Hilt_MyApp"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have an error concerning *Hilt*, I"ve been trying to inject a retrofit interface I created using *Hilt*,

Here is the error:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kotlin20test.Hilt_MyApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.kotlin20test-hKFhgE2D6vBE-1ZkVY-UOA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.kotlin20test-hKFhgE2D6vBE-1ZkVY-UOA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                ... 16 more
```

and Here are my files:

**MyApp**

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp : Application()
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    //View Binding
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kotlin20test"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/gradle/incremental.annotation.processors'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    //Room
    def room_version = "2.2.6"
    def lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"
    // Annotation processor
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"


    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"



    implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0'
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"

    //Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.3'

    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"


    //Activity Result API
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.0-alpha07"
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.3'


    //Retrofit and Gson
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'



    //Dagger Hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.35.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.35.1'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'


}
```

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.50"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    ext.hilt_version = '2.35'
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.35.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.kotlintest">

    <application
        tools:remove="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:name=".Hilt_MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.KotlinTest">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity2"
            ></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".ExampleBroadcast"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried hilt in another application using *Kotlin* but still the same error is produced, I've also read
a couple of questions on the subject her on **Stack Overflow**, and tries some Answers, including
MultiDexApplication.

Edit: Sorry I wrote the wrong **AndroidManifest**, the previous app one was of an
app that had the same error(I'm trying two apps), and I changed the second one's
Application class to **Hilt_MyApp** class before that error showed up in hopes of
trying to solve the error.

Here is the real manifest related to this app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.kotlin20test">

    <application

        android:name="com.kotlin20test.MyApp"
        tools:remove="android:appComponentFactory"
        tools:targetApi="p"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Kotlin20Test">
        <activity android:name="com.kotlin20test.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

'''
```

Comment: is should be `android:name=".MyApp"`

Comment: thank you for letting me notice I gave the wrong **AndroidManifest**, I was quite confused and frustrated because I've spent hours trying to solve that error.

Comment: @IR42 This is not necessary. I tried and tested. Make sure you have installed all the required dependencies. Especially the kapt dependency because people almost ignore this one.

Answer (score 12):

I solved it, it turns out that I did not provide the kapt,

```
id 'kotlin-kapt'
```

and used used implementation instead of kapt so instead of:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.35.1'
```

I provided:

```
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.35.1'
```

hope this helps someone someone

Comment: even after having the kapt, I'm still facing the issue. Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem today, and I saw that it in your gradle too

```
packagingOptions {
   exclude 'META-INF/gradle/incremental.annotation.processors'
}
```

this is how you should do the hilt implementation to avoid using it and fix the problem

```
//Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.42"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.42"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.42"
```

Renamed the application name in manifest.xml to
`android:name=".MyApp"`

Comment: I edited the dependencies with the latest versions.. Actually this solution worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up migrating to KSP after wasting hours with this issue. Please follow this guide for migrating to KSP: https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp

and use this guide for Hilt versions that you should use: https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/ksp.html

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest rename the atributte:

`android:name=".Hilt_MyApp"` to `android:name=".MyApp"`

Comment: This is not necessary. I tried and tested. Make sure you have installed all the required dependencies. Especially the kapt dependency because people almost ignore this one.

Answer (score 0):

> I have seen some **issue's** in your **build.gradle**

You have put

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

in **wrong place** . I mean in dependencies instead of at top in plugins.

And you are also adding two differnt classpath like

```
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.35.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `kapt` instead of `implementation` for the `hilt-compiler`

```
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried every single thing I could find in Stackoverflow answers...

`Build/Clean/Invalid & Restart`, Uninstalling app, reinstalling, Removing hilt and it's annotations, and readding them, but none of those worked. Even tried renaming the class and creating it under another name.

What DID work was, moving the affected class.

So my `WalletFragment` with the annotation `AndroidEntryPoint` was not working and giving that error. Moving it to another package fixed it.