java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.spydar.daggerhilt.App package com.spydar.daggerhilt
This is the error which i am getting right now, after adding the dependencies of dagger hilt and adding the annotations like @HiltAndroidApp and rest too.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.spydar.tour.ToursApplication package com.spydar.tour: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.spydar.tour.ToursApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~c7uFoZidJdo590tOgJZt5w==/com.spydar.tour-hnXBC7Tb1XFe1lWx-_AkQg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~c7uFoZidJdo590tOgJZt5w==/com.spydar.tour-hnXBC7Tb1XFe1lWx-_AkQg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]


Dependencies in :app level gradle file

Project level gradle file

CMD Java Version

Gradle

It should generate java (generated) folder.

did you include the kotlin kapt? This might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67650422/hilt-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-com-kotlin20test-hilt

Ensure to declare your application class in Manifest.
